# Cat won't stop trying to take off her head cone, that keeps her from touching her injury

Tags: cats, pet-selection, injury

[image]

My kitty cut her eye today so we took her to the vet, they gave her eye drops so everything is fine just now. She has a cone to prevent her from pawing it or hitting it off something, but she won't stop trying to take off the cone. Any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Any way to prevent what?

Of *course* she is trying to take the cone off; she has no idea why you are making her wear this annoying thing and she certainly doesn't want to do so. You would object too, if someone put one on you with no explanation you could understand.

But it is better for her to be frustrated and a bit uncomfortable for a while than to risk her interfering with treatment.

You can try to distract her from thinking about the cone, but realistically the answer is that since she will only be wearing it for a short time it isn't worth trying too hard. Give her extra cuddles and/or treats, if you want, but she's just going to have to put up with the cone as long as the doctor said she should.